# MongoDB Aggregation in Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql, morphia

I am trying to map a successful MongoDB Aggregation to morphia but I am not able to get a satisfying result. I fails everytime but I cannot figure out why. Maybe someone of you could help me to state the aggregation correctly in morphia. My MongoDB Query looks like the following:

```
db.user.aggregate([{$match: { roles: "MEMBER" }}, {$group:{_id: "$roles", sum:{$sum: "$payments.2039.amount"}}}])
```

Roles is an array and the aggregation works fine and outputs:

```
{ "_id" : [ "MEMBER" ], "sum" : 100 }
```

I tried to do this in morphia with this java code:

```
final Query<User> query = datastore.createQuery(User.class).field("roles").in(Lists.newArrayList(Role.MEMBER));
final Iterator<AggregatePayments> aggregatePayments = datastore
    .createAggregation(User.class)
    .match(query)
    .group("$roles", grouping("sum", sum("payments." + currentSeason + ".amount")))
    .out(AggregatePayments.class);
```

But, unfortunately, this fails with the following  exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 17276 (Location17276): 'Use of undefined variable: roles' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Use of undefined variable: roles", "code" : 17276, "codeName" : "Location17276" }
```

My problem is now finding out why this works in MongoDB but not in morphia. When I try to leave out the "$" at roles variable for _id in morphia I get the following exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16996 (Location16996): 'insert for $out failed: { connectionId: 1419, err: "can't use an array for _id", code: 2, codeName: "BadValue", n: 0, ok: 1.0 }' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "insert for $out failed: { connectionId: 1419, err: \"can't use an array for _id\", code: 2, codeName: \"BadValue\", n: 0, ok: 1.0 }", "code" : 16996, "codeName" : "Location16996" }
```

Any help appreciated! Thank you very much!

Using MongoDB version 3.6 and current morphia build 1.4-SNAPSHOT.

**EDIT:**
What seems really strange to me is that above Query in MongoDB works but the query generated by morphia not. But the manually edited Query in MongoDB and the generated one by morphia seem to correspond closely to another. Does anyone see any mistakes? Generated query is as follows:

```
11040 [qtp104739310-39] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command  - Sending command '{ "aggregate" : "user", "pipeline" : [{ "$match" : { "roles" : { "$in" : ["MEMBER"] } } }, { "$group" : { "_id" : "$roles", "sum" : { "$sum" : "$payments.2039.amount" } } }, { "$out" : "AggregatePayments" }], "cursor" : { }, "$db" : "sua", "$readPreference" : { "mode" : "primaryPreferred" } }' with request id 19 to database sua on connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:1419}] to server localhost:27017
```

and produces the exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16996 (Location16996): 'insert for $out failed: { connectionId: 1419, err: "can't use an array for _id", code: 2, codeName: "BadValue", n: 0, ok: 1.0 }' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "insert for $out failed: { connectionId: 1419, err: \"can't use an array for _id\", code: 2, codeName: \"BadValue\", n: 0, ok: 1.0 }", "code" : 16996, "codeName" : "Location16996" }
```

When manually editing the query in MongoDB I can also use $group:{_id: "$roles".... Seems quite strange to me...

Comment: I don't use Morphia myself but I always find "unit tests" to be very informative about syntax where documentation may be lacking. A quick browse would suggest this is what you are looking for: https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/tree/master/morphia/src/test/java/org/mongodb/morphia/aggregation

Answer (score 0):

I didn't recognize the difference between morphia's "out()" and "aggregate()" method. "out()" changes the collection in the MongoDB store which was not intended. Using "aggregate()" now solved all problems:

```
final Query<User> query = datastore.createQuery(User.class).field("roles").in(Lists.newArrayList(Role.MEMBER));
final Iterator<AggregatePayments> aggregatePayments = datastore
    .createAggregation(User.class)
    .match(query)
    .group("roles", grouping("sum", sum("payments." + currentSeason + ".amount")))
    .aggregate(AggregatePayments.class);
```

Works now as expected with morphia 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT (most recent build from git master) and MongoDB 3.6.